# 'O' order of a function

Tags: analysis

I'm having some trouble finding the 'O' orders of given functions. I have the following definitions.

Let $\phi(x),\psi(x)$ be real or complex valued functions. Let $x_0$ be a limit point of a set $R$ not necessarily belonging to $R$. We write $$\psi=O(\phi)$$ if there exists a constant $A$, independent of $x$, such that $$|\psi| \leq A|\phi|, \forall x \in R$$

and also that $\psi=O(\phi)$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$ if $ \frac{\psi}{\phi}$ is bounded in $R$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$

My problem is that given some function, say $\psi=\sqrt{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}$ or $\psi=e^{-\cosh(\frac{1}{\epsilon})}$, how do I go about finding a $\phi$ such that $\psi=O(\phi)$?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer for this. Normally you have a function $\phi$ and want to show that $\psi$ is $O(\phi)$. Further it depends on the limit point, a function has different behavior for different limit points.

In your first example, considering you want to look at $\epsilon\to 0$, you have
$$ \sqrt{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}= \sqrt{\epsilon}\sqrt{1-\epsilon}$$
Here the second  term on the RHS is going to unity as $\epsilon\to 0$, so
$$ \sqrt{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}=O(\sqrt{\epsilon}), \epsilon\to 0$$
In the second example you have to look at the behavior of $\cosh(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ if again $\epsilon\to 0$.

Here you have to know something about the functions and how to manipulate them. No  simple rules, sorry.
Yo can/must use all the tools you know.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean, that has made it a little clearer.